# Facebook Graph: Possible to upload photo to /user/account/album? If so, how?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm attempting to set up an app for a small set of known users, all of whom have a sub "page", "account" or whatever the terminology du jour is. The main goal of the app is to publish photos to these sub-accounts in an automated fashion on their behalf.

The crux of the issue seems to be that while I can ask for "manage_pages" to manage the user's sub-accounts and for "publish_stream" which allows me to upload photos to the user's root stream *I can't upload photos to a **subaccount** stream*.

I've been able to do a status update on the sub-account stream (text only), but every time I try to upload a photo (via curl, commandline-style), I get various errors depending on how I try to do it:

http://graph.facebook.com/albumid/photos -> Error #324 requires upload file

http://graph.facebook.com/albumid -> Error #200 application does not have the capability to make this API call.

http://graph.facebook.com/subaccount_id/feed - > Error #100 Source URL is not properly formatted

http://graph.facebook.com/subaccount_id/photos -> Error #324 requires upload file

I've stabbed around in the dark like this for about 4 hours with no luck and am beginning to wonder: ***Is posting a photo to a user's sub-account stream even possible? If so, how?***

(BTW, I have tried doing a text status update with a photo URL -- attempting to circumvent the whole uploading part -- and that doesn't help. The url of the photo appears in the post, but does not show the photo. I'm open to any suggestion that shows photos in a subaccount stream.)

Comment: I have no idea what a “sub-account” is supposed to be.

Comment: Journalist, brand, company, celebrity pages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Only about 5 minutes after posting this, I kind of, sort of found a solution:

First, upload the image to your own web server, s3 bucket, or other location.

Second, use http://graph.facebook.com/subaccount_id/feed with source=http://www.thenewlocationofyourimage.com/image.jpg.

The image shows up in the page stream, albeit as a small thumbnail. Better than nothing, though. If you have better information, PLEASE let me know. Thanks!